# What happens if I cancel pulling by git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am new to git, and have to use it with TortoiseGit. I wanted to pull a whole remote repository but downloading was very slow so I decided to cancel the process.  Before pulling I committed to my local repository.

What happens if I cancel pulling before it downloads everythign, did the unfinished pull messed something up in my local repository?

Comment: Have you noticed any corruption or anything awry with your local repository?

Comment: `git pull` is essentially a `git fetch` and `git merge`. It may cut it off somewhere along this process? Not sure, just sharing ideas.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't notice anything awry.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't have anything to worry about, then.  If you had issues with your repository after the cancellation, then that'd be a concern.

Comment: There should be no problems when you canceled during downloading. You gould only get a not fully updated working tree if you cancel during the merge. - Reusing already downladed objects: possible, but don't expect that.

Answer (score 2):

There should be no problems when you canceled during downloading. You could only get a not fully updated working tree if you cancel during the merge. - Reusing already downladed objects: possible, but don't expect that.

Answer (score 0):

Pull is a fetch followed by a merge, so it depends if it was still fetching, or if it had started merging.  If it was still fetching, then you probably have a temporary file in your .git\objects\pack folder which is taking up space, but not hurting anything (look for a file in that folder without the .idx or .pack extension).  If it had started merging, your working directory may be in a dirty state.  If you run `git status` and your working directory is clean, you're almost certainly fine.